# Ordering post in list by atribute java

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

Is possible to order elements in List indirectly (in Java 7)? Assume having elements of list which are post which have atributs (atributs of type Post) id, text, timestamp (millisec from 1970 - just number type long).
The posts are stored in database (MySQL) and they came as result of different SELECTs. It's because posts is something tweets on twitter - posts which added user, posts of users which user follows and maybe some others. The idea is do some SELECTSs, each get result as list and these lists will be added to one list, which I want to order by atribute (timestamp). Is any easy way to sort it indirectly (from higher to lower - to have newest to oldest posts) by this atribute (timestamp)? I know that List have attribute sort and I should probably do something with that.

Comment: Write a `Comparator` for your `Post` class and use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`

Comment: @SJuan76 FYI, use %20 for spaces and escape parens with \ in link comments.

Comment: But I don't know how to write that damn comparator.

Comment: @user1097772 just read the javadoc for it carefully and google for examples, there are plenty

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a `Set`, and more specifically a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (the basic implementation of it being a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)), instead of a `List`. This will require that your post class implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) of itself, however.

Of course, there is always the option to `ORDER BY` at the database level. This way you can use a classical `List`.

Comment: I'm not sure - isn't problem that the attribute for sorting is not unique, when I would use Set? Theoreticaly there could be more posts with same timestamp.

Comment: You are not limited to comparing timestamps only. You say there is an id in them, this is pretty much unique: if the timestamp is equal, compare the ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the database using Order By clause to get the result in order of timestamp, then you won't have to do sorting at java side.

Comment: Not possible or too complicated query, couse as I wrote in my question I get the list from more than one SELECT on the database, I will do one SELECTs, second, third, ...(cause I have different requirements on them) and then I'll sort it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it. You can do it from query by using `ORDER BY column` or use comparable and comparator to sort objects. link =

> http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/